# JW Player not working on Android device

Tags: mobile, jwplayer

I'm using jwplayer6.6;

when server response：

```
X-UA-Compatible:    IE=EmulateIE9
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Date:   Wed, 04 Dec 2013 03:03:41 GMT
Content-Type:   video/mp4
Content-Length: 3771577
Content-Disposition:    attachment; filename="a.mp4"
Accept-Ranges:  bytes
```

It works fine on desktop browsers(chrome,firefox,ie) and IOS;
But show "Error loading media: File could not be played" on my android chrome browser

Comment: Hi user3064176. Welcome to SO. I formatted your question to include code tags around your server response. This makes it neater and easier to view your question. You should do the same for future questions.

Comment: Can you provide a link?